# Cross namespace communication across pods in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-networkpolicy

How does cross namespace communication across pods in kubernetes? Say webserver & application pod is in namespace A and DB in namespace B. I have created External Name as well but still doesn't work.

Can we have multiple selectors in the deployments.yaml

```
frontend-service

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-express-service
  namespace: db
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: mongo-express
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
```

```
DB-service.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb-service
  namespace: db
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: mongo-express-service.frontend.svc.cluster.local
  selector:
    app: mongodb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

```
$ kubectl get svc -n db
NAME                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP                                        PORT(S)          AGE
mongo-express-service   NodePort       10.103.8.140   <none>                                             8081:32468/TCP   5h20m
mongodb-service         ExternalName   <none>         mongo-express-service.frontend.svc.cluster.local   27017/TCP        5h19m
```

```
$ kubectl get svc -n frontend
NAME                    TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
mongo-express-service   NodePort   10.102.174.70   <none>        8081:30928/TCP   5h20m
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pods in one namespace communicates with the other namespaces without  anyexternal name  or network policies. By default communication takes place between pods unless any denial of traffic is configured via network policies.

I created the db service with clusterIP as usual by associating it with mongodb app in the selector section

```
$ kubectl.exe describe svc mongodb-service -n db

Name:              **mongodb-service**

Namespace:         **db**

Labels:            <none>

Annotations:       <none>

**Selector:          app=mongodb**

Type:              **ClusterIP**

IP Families:       <none>

IP:                10.109.25.141

IPs:               10.109.25.141

Port:              <unset>  27017/TCP

TargetPort:        27017/TCP

Endpoints:         10.0.0.48:27017

Session Affinity:  None

Events:            <none>

$ kubectl.exe get svc -n  db
NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
mongodb-service   ClusterIP   10.109.25.141   <none>        27017/TCP   47m
```

Then in the frontend namespace I updated the configmap with the nameofservice.anothernamespace.svc.cluster.local (mongodb-service.db.svc.cluster.local).

```
apiVersion: v1

kind: ConfigMap

metadata:

  name: mongodb-configmap

  namespace: frontend

data:

  database_url: mongodb-service.db.svc.cluster.local
```

pods in frontend namespace are working fine.

```
$ kubectl.exe get pods,svc -n  frontend

NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE

pod/mongo-express-78fcf796b8-m4xhj   1/1     Running   8          19m

pod/mongo-express-78fcf796b8-mf4bf   1/1     Running   8          19m

pod/mongo-express-78fcf796b8-zgjkh   1/1     Running   8          19m

NAME                            TYPE       CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE

service/mongo-express-service   NodePort   10.105.0.117   <none>        8081:31097/TCP   19m
```

Answer (score 1):

you should create a network policy:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: simple-policy
  namespace: db
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo-db
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: frontend
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: mongo-express
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
  egress:
  - to:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: frontend
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: mongodb-express
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
```

you can slim it down by the restrictions you like whether is the entire namespace, just two pods and with a specific port or all of them.

check out more in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/)

Comment: Noam, The above solution did not help me. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: did you modify the values to your usage?

Comment: yes I did, also remove external service  ` podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: frontend
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: mongo-express
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
  egress:
  - to:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: frontend
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: mongo-express
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017`

Comment: then what signifies that you the *from namespace*?

Comment: My cluster is in EKS. For network policies to work, do I need to install any network plugin(calico)?  https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/

Comment: I'm not really sure cause I'm not using EKS. I was speaking for k8s in general, I'll add the EKS tag

Comment: I tried network policies and external name in the service as well, but pods in different name spaces aren't communicating even though the ping is successful

Comment: Well ping and http requests use different protocols altogether, and if basic COMS work maybe you should check service ports between the pods to make sure they're the right ones

Comment: I modified your network policy code snippet to match the policy at my end. The application is in 'frontend namespace' with label 'mongo-express' and mongodb is in 'db namespace' with label 'mongo-db' and mongodb  port is '27017'